# python - create list in function

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python and have the below script that works, but I want to use the results to create a list that I can call outside the function. When I print list the right results are produced. The `print x` does nothing.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

def hits_one_spider():
    #page = 1
    #while page <= max_pages:
        url = "http://www.siriusxm.ca/hits-1-weekend-countdown/"
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.find('div', {'class': 'entry-content'}).findAll('li'):
            #href = "http://www.siriusxm.ca/" + link.get('href')
            title = link.string
            #print(href)
            #print(title)
            return list

x = hits_one_spider()

print x
```

Comment: I don't see you assigning any value to the list variable that you are trying to return in your function. Can you please explain with an example what exactly are you expecting inside your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you say `return list` in the for loop. Thus it returns after the first iteration. Further you aren't actually returning it as a list, by doing it like that.

What you instead what is something like this:

```
lst = []
for link in soup.find('div', {'class': 'entry-content'}).findAll('li'):
    lst.append(link.string)
return lst
```

Which results in returning (and printing) a list containing:

```
[
    "Sam Smith – Stay With Me",
    "Kongos – Come With Me Now",
    "Iggy Azalea – Fancy feat. Charli XCX",
    "OneRepublic – Love Runs Out",
    "Magic! – Rude",
    ... and a lot more ...
    "Oh Honey – Be Okay",
    "Katy Perry – Birthday",
    "Neon Trees – Sleeping With A Friend",
    "Cher Lloyd – Sirens",
]
```